# Bash Error: No Such File or Directory after Uninstalling Anaconda

Tags: windows-10, anaconda, git-bash

After Uninstalling Anaconda I get a "No such file or directory" error in Git Bash each time I open the prompt.I am using Windows 10 Git Bash.

I've looked at all my PATH variables and none of them reference Anaconda. I've also searched all the associated bash files to see if they call for that file on startup. I don't see anything using VSCode 'find in files'.

```
bash: /c/Users/eme/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe: No such 
file or directory

EME@PF166XR4 MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$
```

It appears bash is looking for this file (which I purposefully deleted) but I cannot find which file is calling for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

> This error is caused by .bash_profile file.
>  It is the
> configuration file for user environments.
>  It always tries to load
> conda files.

To get rid of this error, first find **.bash_profile**.
Common location is `C:\Users\your_username`

After you find it, you should change the content of the file using git.

- go to the file location:  `cd C:\Users\your_username`
- go indside the file  `nano .bash_profile`
- delete everything related to **conda**
- save and exit

**Do NOT just delete the file. There might be unexpected bugs**

Answer (score 3):

try to execut this command in your Git Bash

```
conda init bash
```

Seems to have fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have uninstalled conda on windows and are still able to see the above message, edit  ~/.bash_profile with the following commands:

```
cd ~
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Delete the contents related to conda.exe and save. This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` which might still reference an Anaconda resource.

And see if the issue persists when using Git in a simplified PATH.

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
set GIT_HOME=C:\Path\to\Git
set PATH=%GIT_HOME%;%GIT_HOME%\bin;%GIT_HOME%\usr\bin;%PATH%
```