# conda activate in WSL2 | both / and \

Tags: anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, anaconda3

Goal: setup **conda** in **WSL2**.

I have Anaconda3 with venvs in it.

I've just installed WSL2 and want to use conda within it.

When activating conda, I get this filepath:

```
$ conda activate myvenv
-bash: C:/Users/me/Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe: No such file or directory
```

The filepath does exist, but this uses `/` and `\`.

Please help.

---

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen$ cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
. /mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
. /mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
. /mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
. '/mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d'/conda.sh
```

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen$ cat ~/.profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen$ .bash_profile
.bash_profile: command not found
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/lumada-catalog/synthetic-data-gen$ cat .bash_profile
cat: .bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Context: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245586/discussion-between-vonc-and-nick-wassermann

Comment: It seems that you are trying to activate one of you Win conda environments from WSL. Just to clarify  - you had Anaconda3 installed in Windows, you installed WSL2 and now want to activate conda environment of that same Anacoda3 installation from WSL session?  If yes, then this will not work, you need to install Anaconda to your WSL distribution. To save some time & space, you might want opt for Miniconda instead. You can then export your existing environment in Windows and import it in WSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy `envs` folder,
- Run `Uninstall.exe`,
- Download and install `Anaconda3` (ticking both boxes at setup),
- Pasted `envs` folder into the new `Anaconda3` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in a [past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57046367/6309) checking your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.
See also your `.bash_profile`, in your WSL2 session.

The idea is to check if there is anything related to `conda`, including a path with mixed separator.

Comment: Hey, I've updated post with both outputs

Comment: @YetAnotherAccount OK. What does `/mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` include?

Comment: `cat: /mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory` but checking file explorer it does exist

Comment: @YetAnotherAccount OK, what does that file contain? And would `cat C:/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` work

Comment: It just opens a blank Bash window. The `cat` command, oddly, doesn't work either @VonC

Comment: @YetAnotherAccount OK. I suspect this failed sourced file `. /mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` can be problematic, especially if the file is not readable at that path. Can you at least keep the only the first one in your `~/.profile`?

Comment: Why would `$ conda` return `C:/Users/dabell/Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe: No such file or directory`? I feel like this is the problem

Comment: @YetAnotherAccount Indeed. You need to make sure `/mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` exists and can be read